# How to set the value in extjs 3.2

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using extjs 3. And I have two textfield. I want to `setvalue` of first `textarea` in second. I am using

`Ext.getCmp('firstText).getValue()` by which I am getting value of first textarea. But when I am using `setValue` in second textarea then it failed. Setvalue is not function in extjs3. What is the alternate option I can use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `value` property of the field to set value.

```
Ext.getCmp('secondText').value = Ext.getCmp('firstText').getValue();
```